# Use a greedy ear decomposition to prove that every 2-connected claw-free graph G has [n(G)/3]

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

This question from problem of chapter of Introduction to Graph Theory

A greedy ear decomposition of a 2-connected graph is an ear decomposition that begins with a longest cycle and iteratively adds a longest possible ear. Use a greedy ear decomposition to prove that every 2-connected claw-free graph G has [n(G)/3] pairwise-disjoint copies of P3 [Kaneko–Kelmans–Nishimura[2000]).

I try to draw some simple but I still can't to finish it.
The results that I got.
Let C be the longest cycle of C.If xy,xz are two edges of C and w is a vertex of not in C have xw is an edge,then yz must be an edge, otherwise wx or wy is an edge by G is claw-free,then we can find a  cycle longer than C.

Comment: Just to note, on Doug West's [website](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~west/igt/igt2comm.html) it is noted that this exercise (Exr4.2.10) is far too difficult for this text. Looking at the source material "On packing 3‐vertex paths in a graph," the proof seems a bit involved.

Comment: Thank you answer,I have done the exercise via the paper,On Packing 3-Vertex
Paths in a Graph

Comment: You're welcome :)